# Problems using achicago package to create a bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, errors, chicago-style

I've been having trouble using achicago package, I tried to run this example:

```
\documentclass[15pt]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{dialogue}
\usepackage{achicago}
\usepackage{attrib}
\usepackage{lips}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}

\begin{dialogue}
\speak{Vladimir} Whare are all these corpses from?
\speak{Estragon} These skeletons.
\par\lips\par
\speak{Vladimir} A charnel-house! A charnel-house! \attrib{\cite[41]    {beckett:godot}}
\attrib{\play{Waiting for Godot}, 41 \normalcitations\cite{beckett:godot}}
\medskip
\direct{
Estragon has exited offstage to right and left and come ‘‘panting’’ back
and fallen into Vladimir’s arms. \emph{---Ed.}
}
\speak{Estragon} I’m in hell!
\speak{Vladimir} Where were you?
\speak{Estragon} They’re coming there too!
\speak{Vladimir} We’re surrounded! \direct{\refer{Estragon} makes a rush
towards back.} Imbecile! There’s no way out there.
\direct{\refer{He} takes \refer{Estragon} by the arms
and drags him towards front. Gesture towards front.}
There! Not a soul in sight! Off you go! Quick!
\direct{\refer{He} pushes \refer{Estragon} towards
auditorium. \refer{Estragon} recoils in horror.} You
won’t? \direct{\refer{He} contemplates auditorium.}
Well I can understand that. Wait till I see.
\direct{\refer{He} reflects.} Your only hope left is to
disappear.

\attrib{47}
\end{dialogue}
Hello \cite{beckett:godot}\\

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

but I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@listctr 

l.3 \bibitem{beckett:godot}

?
```

The content of the biblio.bib file is the following:

```
@book{beckett:godot,
Author = {Samuel Beckett},
Publisher = {Grove Press},
Title = {Waiting for Godot},
Year = {1984}}
```

Any help will be welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use also

```
\bibliographystyle{achicago}
```

instead of plain.